# How do I host a rest service with autofac and wcf?

Tags: wcf, rest, autofac

Following this guide I managed to get a service working over iis with was.
https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration#Self-Hosted_Services

However, I also need it host a rest service. I could actually live with only rest.

But with the documentation available I have not been successful yet.

Does anyone have a good guide for getting it working with rest service with wcf(was)+autofac?

I do not seem to get the endpoint right, no endpoint at all actually.

My code, where did I miss something?

```
namespace WcfServiceHost.Infrastructure
{
    public class AutofacContainerBuilder
    {

        public static IContainer BuildContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<LoginFactory>().As<ILoginFactory>();
            builder.RegisterType<SupplierHandler>().As<ISupplierHandler>();
            builder.RegisterType<UserHandler>().As<IUserHandler>();
            builder.RegisterType<SupplierRepository>().As<ISupplierRepository>();
            builder.RegisterType<TidsamProductSupplierProxy>().As<ILogin>();

            builder.RegisterType<StoreService>().As<IStoreService>();
            //builder.RegisterType<StoreService>();

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}



<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="Services.IStoreService, Services" 
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"
     %>



namespace WcfServiceHost.App_Code
// ReSharper restore CheckNamespace
{
    public static class AppStart
    {
        public static void AppInitialize()
        {
            // Put your container initialization here.
            // build and set container in application start
            IContainer container = AutofacContainerBuilder.BuildContainer();
            AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;

            // AutofacWebServiceHostFactory  AutofacServiceHostFactory
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("StoreService", new RestServiceHostFactory<IStoreService>(), typeof(StoreService)));

        }
    }
}



 public class RestServiceHostFactory<TServiceContract> : AutofacWebServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
            var webBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior
            {
                AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true,
                HelpEnabled = true,
                FaultExceptionEnabled = true
            };
            var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TServiceContract), new WebHttpBinding(), "Rest");
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { HelpEnabled = true });
            endpoint.Name = "rest";
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(webBehavior);

            return host;
        }

    }
```

config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory"
         relativeAddress="~/StoreService.svc"
         service="Services.StoreService" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" />
    </handlers>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Then I do get an endpoint. But as soon as I change to AutofacWebServiceHostFactory I get no endpoint and no rest/help. However, I can query the rest services in IStoreService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this. I removed the reference to the autofac AutofacServiceHostFactory in the config. Then I wrote endpoints manually with behaviors.

I used AutofacServiceHostFactory in the .svc file for the service.

This was not the way I'd prefer to do it but otherwise I didn't both the rest endpoint and the basichttp soap endpoint to work.

If someone has a better solution, I'll give you the answer.

---

@John Meyer 
Upon request for my code sample, I managed to find some old code.

The service like EmailService.svc in my folder Services, edit like so:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
Service="Services.IEmailService, Services" 
Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf"
 %>
```

in web.config

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="x" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
```

AppStart class

```
public static class AppStart
{
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
        IContainer container = AutofacContainerBuilder.BuildContainer();
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;}
}
...
```

I seperated the container to another class.
Dont forget the correct using
    using Autofac;

and the method in the class to set up the container

```
public static IContainer BuildContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<EmailService>().As<IEmailService>();
            return builder.Build();
        }
```

Comment: "...I wrote endpoints manually with behaviors." - Can you show the web.config for this?

Comment: This was several years ago. I will have a look when I get home from work if I can find some lab code that I might still have. In more recent projects I've used Simple Injector which is supposed to be a bit faster, but was also easier to figure out how to work with, if your in a hurry I suggest you look at that first.

Answer (score 0):

A registration of REST WCF service is almost similar to registration non-REST WCF service. Only changed a few things: bindings, endpoints and service contract.

### Modified example from the autofac wiki with WCF REST service (very simplified).

The interface and implementation for the logger that will be the dependency.

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Write(string message);
}

public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

The contract and implementation for the rest wcf service.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IEchoService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/Echo/{message}")]
    string RestEcho(string message);
}

public class EchoService : IEchoService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public EchoService(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public string RestEcho(string message)
    {
        _logger.Write(message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

The Console Application code for building the container and hosting the web service.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(c => new Logger()).As<ILogger>();
        builder.Register(c => new EchoService(c.Resolve<ILogger>())).As<IEchoService>();

        using (IContainer container = builder.Build())
        {
            Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/EchoService");
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(EchoService), address);

            var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);
            var description = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IEchoService));
            var endpoint = new ServiceEndpoint(description, binding, endpointAddress);
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior { HelpEnabled = true });
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(endpoint);

            host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IEchoService>(container);

            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true, HttpGetUrl = address });
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The host has been opened.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

For testing, run any browser and open a url `http://localhost:8080/EchoService/Echo/test_test`

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I'll look throu it and see if I missed something that could help me. However, I asked for help about wcf(was)  since I'll host it on a ms 2012 server on the iis. When I followed the guide about it on autofac wiki it works for soap but when I switch to webhttpbinding and use the AutofacWebServiceHostFactory instead I do not get it working. If you can do that, I'll by you a couple of beers if you happen to live in Stockholm!

Comment: I just updated my original post with how far I got, slightly modified code.